# Как увеличить объем диска в Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, файлы

У меня есть сервер под управлением OC Ubuntu 20.04. Часто вываливаются ошибки в моих Docker приложениях о  том, что нехватает места на диске.

Вот что выводит команда `df -h`:

[image: df- h]

Я не понимаю почему мои 19GB заняты в разделе overlay/loop и почему раздел `/` практически занят, хотя на сервере запущены только два веб-приложения. Лишние Docker-образы и контейнеры я почистил. Как мне освободить место в системе или расширить мой основной раздел?

Comment: Возьмите ncdu и посмотрите, что-где конкретно занимает место

Comment: обрати внимание на папки с логами и с локальной почтой

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри что тебе показывает **docker system df**

```
TYPE            TOTAL     ACTIVE    SIZE      RECLAIMABLE
Images          15        1         5.756GB   4.642GB (80%)
Containers      1         0         8.944GB   8.944GB (100%)
Local Volumes   23        2         1.857GB   1.857GB (99%)
Build Cache     9         0         824B      824B
```

Потом можно выполнить

```
docker system prune
WARNING! This will remove:
  - all stopped containers
  - all networks not used by at least one container
  - all dangling images
  - all dangling build cache
```